# Calculating the area of gridded data (equidistant in degrees)

Tags: python, numpy, geospatial

I have some gridded data (180 latitude boxes by 360 longitude boxes), which can be downloaded here containing sea ice data (0 = no ice, 1 =  complete ice). https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApWaJaYUUERKjqAP-3K48AuUAFgPXQ

I'm trying to compute the Arctic ice extent, i.e. if a grid box is over 15% ice (0.15), then the grid box is counted as ice covered and the area of that grid box is added to an array. The total area is then summed at the end. I'm getting values of 16.08, which is much higher than I need (Data is for December 2014, real values are here (ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/DATASETS/NOAA/G02135/north/monthly/data/N_12_extent_v2.1.csv) should be 12.4 ish.

I know that given resolution there will be a discrepancy (topography edge for example), but not that large.

Code I used is below:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

Data = Dataset('Ice.nc','r')

ICE = np.squeeze(np.squeeze(Data.variables['sic'][:]))
Lat = Data.variables['latitude'][:]
Lon = Data.variables['longitude'][:]

Ice_Exten = np.zeros((360,180))


for i in range(0,360):
    for j in range(90,180):  #just northern hemisphere

        if ICE[j,i] > 0.15 and ICE[j,i] <= 1.0:

            Ice_Exten[i,j] = 12321. * np.cos(np.radians(Lat[j]))

print np.sum(Ice_Exten)/1e6
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you use the mean latitude of a grid box, i.e., `np.cos(np.radians(j-89.5))`? FWIW, you could make that double loop more efficient by making latitude the outer loop & calculate the cosine outside the longitude loop.

Comment: Forgot to change that, that line should of been `Ice_Exten[i,j] = 12321. * np.cos(np.radians(Lat[j]))` (not that it makes much difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no issue with the code; rather the discrepancies were due to the land/sea mask being used, and interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add the total ice area instead of rouding it up to 1?

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

Data = Dataset('Ice.nc','r')

ICE = np.squeeze(np.squeeze(Data.variables['sic'][:]))
Lat = Data.variables['latitude'][:]
Lon = Data.variables['longitude'][:]

Ice_Exten = np.zeros((360,180))


for i in range(0,360):
    for j in range(90,180):  #just northern hemisphere

        if ICE[j,i] > 0.15 and ICE[j,i] <= 1.0:

            Ice_Exten[i,j] = 12321. * np.cos(np.radians(j-90.)) * ICE[j,i]

print np.sum(Ice_Exten)/1e6
```

output:

```
12.7085786161
```

Comment: Because that's the calculation of ice area, rather than extent (i.e. the final column of ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/DATASETS/NOAA/G02135/north/monthly/data/N_12_extent_v2.1.csv )

Comment: "Sea ice extent is a measurement of the area of ocean where there is at least some sea ice. Usually, scientists define a threshold of minimum concentration to mark the ice edge; the most common cutoff is at 15 percent. Scientists use the 15 percent cutoff because it provides the most consistent agreement between satellite and ground observations."  https://nsidc.org/cryosphere/quickfacts/seaice.html